# Clojure/JDBC/Postgresql: I am trying to update a timestamp value in postgresql from a string, getting an error

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure, timestamp

Using the clojure jdbc library with postgresql.  I have a table "xxx" with a timestamp column "created_at" in postgresql, and I have a string containing a date in the right format.  Doing an insert fails:

```
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])

(sql/with-connection *db*
  (sql/insert-record :xxx {:created_at "Thu Feb 09 10:38:01 +0000 2012"}))
```

Here is the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "created_at" 
is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying
```

So I understand that postgres requires a timestamp value, but how do I convert my string representation of the date into something postgres will accept?  java.util.Date fails also, and I can't find any docs on the clojure postgres library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to pass in a `java.sql.Timestamp` instance. To parse your string into one using [`clj-time`](http://github.com/seancorfield/clj-time), a [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)-wrapping library for Clojure, you'd do something along the following lines:

```
(require '(clj-time [format :as timef] [coerce :as timec])

(->> "Thu Feb 09 10:38:01 +0000 2012"
     (timef/parse (timef/formatter "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"))
     timec/to-timestamp)
```

The returned value can then be passed to PostgreSQL via JDBC.

In case you're obtaining the date in some other string format and converting it to this one, you could skip the conversion and provide an appropriate formatter for the original representation. There are quite a few available by default in the `clj-time.format/formatters` map, say `(clj-time.format/show-formatters)` at the REPL to see a list with examples. Also, `clj-time.coerce/from-string` tries all default formatters in sequence returning the value of the first succeeding parse (`nil` if there is none). If you're obtaining the date as a `java.util.Date` or a `long`, see `from-date` and `from-long` in the same namespace.

Use `[clj-time "0.3.6"]` as the dependency specifier in your `project.clj` if you decide to use `clj-time`.

Alternatively, you could use some other way of parsing your timestamp string into a `java.sql.Timestamp`; `Timestamp` itself can parse a different string representation:

```
(java.sql.Timestamp/valueOf "2004-10-19 10:23:54")
```

`clj-time` is the most sane way of dealing with date and time in Clojure, though, so it's likely to be worth your while.

Comment: clj-time is indeed the way to handle time in Clojure, thanks much!

Comment: Since this is an old answer, and I'm one of the maintainers of clj-time, I'll note that clj-time is deprecated and we encourage folks to migrate to Java Time (built-in as of Java 8) or one of its wrapper libraries -- per the README of clj-time!